# Creating automatically DOM tree diagram from HTML file

Tags: html, dom, diagram

**Question: Is any way (any tool) to create automatically DOM tree diagram from HTML file?**

I want to create diagrams like below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean like what https://gojs.net/latest/samples/DOMTree.html does to show the DOM tree of its own page?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Live DOM Viewer](https://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/).
It is a useful tool that generates a basic DOM structure from your HTML code. Just make sure to remove any *meta* tag in your HTML code. Else it won't work.